# PHP file_put_contents: Create new file after 250,000 lines of code

Tags: php, xml, seo, search-engine

I'm using a php script to generate my websites sitemap.xml

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
  $sql = "SELECT `title`,`id`,`type`,`updated_at` FROM `titles`";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) {
    // Parse the result set, and add the URL in the XML structure
    foreach($result as $row) {

      $xmlsitemap .=  '<url>
<loc>/'. $type1 .'/'. $row['id'] .'-'. $string .'</loc>
<lastmod>'. $date1 .'</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>';
    }
  }
$xmlsitemap .= '</urlset>';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xmlsitemap);          // saves the sitemap on server
```

Currently I am sitting at about 37,000 urls in my sitemap.xml file.

I know the sitemap has an upper limit of 50,000 urls.  Is there an easy way in php to tell the script to create a second sitemap2.xml once a certain number of lines eg. every url will have approx 6 lines of code, so I would estimate the new file should be created when 250,000 lines of code has been reached?

Also what is the best way to include multiple sitemap.xml files in your server root, so that all the sitemap files will be read by search engine bots?

Answer (score 0):

You need add iterator to `foreach`. And create new file if iterator >=50.000